# All different notations of an arithmetic expression?

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic, algebra-precalculus

There is a fixed arithmetic expression with $+$ and $\times$ operators, some variables, and no constants. How can I efficiently generate all its different notations? Two expressions are considered different if the resulting expression trees are not isomorphic. The corresponding operands of every operation must be specified; thus, brackets must be used when necessary.

Example 1: All different notations of $a+b+c$

- $(a+b)+c$
- $a+(b+c)$
- $b+(a+c)$

Example 2: $a\times(b+c)$

- $a\times(b+c)$
- $a\times b+a\times c$

Example 3: $a\times a+b\times b+a\times b+a\times b$:

- $((a\times a+b\times b)+a\times b)+a\times b$
- $(a\times a+b\times b)+(a\times b+a\times b)$
- $(a\times a+a\times b)+(b\times b+a\times b)$
- $((a\times a+a\times b)+b\times b)+a\times b$
- $((a\times a+a\times b)+a\times b)+b\times b$
- $a\times (a+b)+(b\times b+a\times b)$
- $(a\times (a+b)+b\times b)+a\times b$
- $(a\times (a+b)+a\times b)+b\times b$
- $b\times (a+b)+(a\times a+a\times b)$
- $(b\times (a+b)+a\times a)+a\times b$
- $(b\times (a+b)+a\times b)+a\times a$
- $a\times(a+b)+b\times(a+b)$
- $(a+b)\times(a+b)$

I hope I'm not missing any notation for the last example. I should also note that for this example, a notation like $(a\times a)+b\times b+2\times a\times b$ is not allowed as it contains constants.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are more:
$$a+b+c=(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)=(b+a)+c=b+(a+c)=(a+c)+b=$$
$$=a+(c+b)=(c+a)+b=c+(a+b)=(b+c)+a=$$
$$=b+(c+a)=(c+b)+a=c+(b+a).$$

Comment: The order of the operator's operands does not count; thus, (a+b)+c and (b+a)+c are counted as one. Moreover, I seek the approach not the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Robert I just saw the expression $b+(a+c)$ in your post.

Comment: In example 1, I have written 3 different notations. They are different as they have at least one operator with different set of operands. (a+b)+c is the same as (b+a)+c because {a,b}={b,a} and {{a,b},c}={{b,a},c} but b+(a+c) is different from a+(b+c) because {a,c} != {b,c} or because {b,{a,c}} != {a,{b,c}}.

Comment: @Robert If so, $a+b+c=b+(a+c)$ follows from the first and the second: $b+(a+c)=(b+a)+c=(a+b)+c=a+b+c.$

Comment: I'm not sure if I've got your point. Do you mean that why $a+b+c$ is not counted as one notation?

Comment: @Robert I say that if $a+b=b+a$ is given, so for writing $a+b+c$ its enough the following property: $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c).$ The writing $a+b+c=b+(a+c)$ is not necessary. See my previous comment.

Comment: Expressions that make two isomorphic expression trees are considered the same. I do not understand what you mean by "this equality follows from the other". Obviously, they are all equal but those making isomorphic trees are counted once.